# Check if string contains character not on list

Tags: javascript

For example, I have an approved list of characters: "a", "b", and "c".

So if I had the string:

```
var string = "aaabc8abccc";
```

I would like the script to detect the fact that the "8" is not "a", "b", or "c" and output:

```
var output = "aaabc<span style='color:red;'>8</span>abccc";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var strn= "aaabc8abccc";
var chrs = 'abc';
strn=strn.replace(new RegExp('([^'+chrs+'])','g'),'<span style="color:red">$1</span>');
```

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, there was some initial turbulence with the code, but it works now.

Answer (score 5):

Regex:

```
result = subject.replace(/[^abc]/ig, "<span style='color:red;'>$&</span>");
```

Comment: @qwertymk, It matches the matched string. I've always loved: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with regular expressions using `string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)`

In your case it will be something like

```
string.replace(/^[a-z]*/,"<span>$1</span>")
```